# Custom Permalink to remove category word , keeping posts permalink with date?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, permalinks, url-rewriting

I have my post links like this:

```
//abc.com/2018/09/abc-dhs-djs.com/
```

and for category like this:

```
//abc.com/category/mycat/
```

and finally  for tags its like:

```
//abc.com/tag/mytag/
```

I want to remove the category and tag word out of the permalinks.

Before it I have tried many ways like this:

```
Going  to Settings >> Permalinks and select Custom and enter: /%category%/%postname%/
Next set your Category Base to .
```

This removes the category word for category links but it additionally affects the normal post links too, so all the normal posts have a category in their link  and the dates are also removed from the post links like this :

```
//abc.com/mycat/abc-dhs-djs.com/.
```

As well as it gives 404 error on sub-category links.

Also it will not work on tag links.

So I need a solution to remove the category, tag words from permalink and keep the posts permalink with date only.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic